# Python: How to execute more than 1 command over SSH without loggin in every command

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I need to execute 2 commands on a remote machine (Ubuntu Mate 16.04) over SSH using a Python script.

`run_pigpiod_remote` runs a daemon on a remote RPi, as noted from #Line0 in code below. #Line1 makes SSH link and execute the daemon `pigpiod` as needed.

In order to verify successful run, I wish to use `pgrep -x pigpiod` as noted in #Line2. As #Line2 is written- I need to enter password again.

How can I avoid entering password so many times (entering SSH, running `sudo` , and 3rd for #Line2 )

```
def run_pigpiod_remote(adress):
    if ip[0]==adress:
        print(adress,"is a local machine")
        run_pigpiod_local()
    else: #Line0
        print(adress," is a remote machine")
        result = subprocess.run(['ssh','-t','guy@'+adress,'sudo','pigpiod']) #Line1
        result2 = subprocess.run(['ssh','-t','guy@'+adress, "pgrep -x ", "pigpiod"]) #Line2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   subprocess.run(['ssh','-t','guy@'+adress,'sudo pigpiod && pgrep -x pigpiod'])
```

Comment: OK! it works good. It is a nice way solving it. How can I retireve PID (not only on screen ) ? this way code will confirm a successfull run.

Comment: Try subprocess.check_output. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output If your ssh outputs something, you can check the output and validate command success.